# Disable android.enableJetifier for specific module or depedency

Tags: android, gradle, androidx

Running Android Studio 3.2 with the following settings in my `gradle.properties`:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

I have a native project with some C/Java code. With these settings, the compilation fails with the following error message:

> org.gradle.api.artifacts.transform.ArtifactTransformException: Failed
>   to transform file 'android.jar' to match attributes
>   {artifactType=processed-jar} using transform JetifyTransform
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to transform
>   'C:\Android\sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar' using Jetifier.

I believe it doesn't like my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
...
dependencies {
   implementation files("${mySdkDir}/android.jar")
}
```

I know I can globally turn off `enableJetifier` which would indeed make *this* error go away. However, I only want to disable the jetifier for this specific module/dependency.

**How do I set `enableJetifier=false` for a native/java module project?**

Answer (score 1):

The question probably isn't how to disable the Jetifier for the module -

because this is coming from using the wrong plugin for the module.

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
// apply plugin: "com.android.library"

android {
    ...
}
```

There is no way to disable the Jetifier for a module, because it is a project-wide feature... and so the only way around this is not to have `android.jar` being explicitly listed in the `dependencies` block. It's not even meant to be packaged, therefore it has lost nothing in there - and it's not meant to be processed by the Jetifier, which merely is the result of having it declared as a dependency.

Comment: The fact that an external `.jar` (in this case the very `android.jar`) crashed the jetifier was confirmed as a bug by Google and subsequently fixed. You are correct that the jetifier cannot be disabled on module level.

Comment: @l33t it's absolutely pointless to use the Jetifier on the framework jar, because there won't be the expected `com.android.support` namespace to transform into `androidx`. Building Android applications with the Java plugin is the root cause; wouldn't consider it a bug, but rather an abusive utilization of the tools available. the only flaw here is, that it even tries to transform the framework jar.

Comment: Usually, when a piece of software crashes you call it a bug. Being able to reproduce this crash using the framework jar is, well, an easy way to reproduce the crash (usually appreciated by developers). Building Android *libraries* as java plugins certainly is a less common thing to do, but it's perfectly valid.